# How to test function that does not return value in Python

Tags: python, testing, mocking

How Can I **test** a function that does not return value. My function deletes aws s3 bucket directory and files inside it. It checks whether delete function returns 200 or other http status and after that writes to log file.

```
import boto3 as boto3
import logging

def s3():
    return boto3.resource(
        service_name='s3',region_name='us-east',
        aws_access_key_id='key_value',aws_secret_access_key='secret_access_key')


def delete_directory(bucket, key):

    retries_cnt = 3
    logging.info("Deleting directory s3://%s/%s", bucket, key)
    my_bucket = s3().Bucket(bucket)

    while retries_cnt > 0:
        s3_result_json = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key).delete()
        s3_http_status = s3_result_json[0]['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
        if s3_http_status == 200:
            logging.info("Directory s3://%s/%s was removed.", bucket, key)
            break
        else:
            retries_cnt = retries_cnt - 1
            if retries_cnt <= 0:
                logging.info("Directory s3://%s/%s was not removed", bucket, key)
```

I read on the internet that I can mock this function. But how Can I mock this function and what to mock?

Comment: By `delete function` did you mean `delete_directory function` ?

Comment: no ```my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key).delete()```  this line returns list of json after deleting directory in aws, and inside of it HTTPStatusCode. I mean this delete function